# Web scraping app on web host

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a web scraping app in .NET and would like to have it hosted by some party such as arvixe.

The problem is that I do not understand web hosting solutions well and in addition, I'm coming from a desktop background.

What's the best way (worker threads to scrape on a timed loop? some kind of process) for me to write a app that runs on this host and collects data (web scraping) and then saves that to a sql server database?

I would really appreciate a little detail, as I am fairly new to the web space.

Comment: I don't think your host would like that very much...

Comment: @Radu, why's that?  Is there an etiquette here that I am breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the application I created some time ago that crawles web and gets some data:

https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/TddDemand

It implements web crawler + EF4 storage.

It is actually class libraly + console application, but class library could be used as a part of ASP.NET Web Application - no problems here.

But, I don't really understand why you need a web site for that. For this scenario simple application (service) is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the HttpWebRequest class to scrap data from other server in your asp.net web application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx